# How to assert that an error message equals to certain char expression

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception

I am trying to call a function from my `Calculator` class in a test class.
How do I assert that exception message thrown by `Calculator` equals to one I expect?

My calculator code:

```
void Calculator::add() {
    if (_stack.empty()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("empty stack");
    }
    else if (_stack.size() == 1) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Wrong Value");
    }
    else if (_stack.size() > 2) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Wrong Value");
    }
    else {
        double res = this->pop() + this->pop();
        this->push(res);
    }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
TEST_METHOD(should_throw_error_if_stack_is_empty) {

    Assert::AreEqual([] {
            Calculator* myCalculator = new Calculator();
            try {
                myCalculator->add();
            }
            catch (std::runtime_error const& ex)
            {
                return (ex.what());
            }
        }, "empty stack");

    }
```

The reason it does not work: Value returned by lambda function has type `const char*` while my expression type is `const char`. How should I do it?

And is the approach I follow a good practice in general? I mean catching the exceptions thrown by class in a unit test?

Comment: `std::string{"empty stack"}` would fix the comparison.

Comment: You might want to add specific "custom" exception, so you can catch by type.

Comment: `Calculator* myCalculator = new Calculator();` should be `Calculator myCalculator;`: No (extra) allocation needed, no memleak.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it will fix it but I have read that it is not a good practice to throw a string isn't it? no way to do it with const char?

Comment: I didn't say to throw `std::string`, just comparing to it. (so compare content instead of random pointer).

Comment: Sorry I do not understand.`what()` returns a pointer  `const char*` while expected value is `const char`. Where could I put `std::string`?

Comment: In your `Assert::AreEqual`. Btw, not all paths return value. (so if `myCalculator->add();` doesn't throw, you have UB).

Comment: Doesn't your UT's framework have something to directly check exception  ?

Comment: If I put it in assert I still get the same error. because `std::string` and `const char*` are incomparable. It is MS Test framework and there is a function that checks if exception is thrown. However I prefer to check the message and not the fact of throwing. 
I doubt about the correctness of all this at all. My class just throws something that I catch in unit tests. Does it look like a right design?

Comment: For user point of view, you don't want to check error message in code. In UTs, it might be different. To avoid to repeat error message, I would put them somewhere (static const member of calculator, in global error message table, ...) then comparing pointer would be possible. And for your check in `Assert::AreEqual`, if it doesn't handle conversion, you can still also return `std::string` in your lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks I did it this way, comparing string returned from lambda with a string representation of a message. In general as I have found the best practice is to use `Assert::ExpectException` as we are interested just in a fact that the exception is thorwn and not in exception message